# How can I validate a pin using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble with this problem. Any feedback much appreciated.

"ATM machines allow 4 or 6 digit PIN codes and PIN codes cannot contain anything but exactly 4 digits or exactly 6 digits.

If the function is passed a valid PIN string, return true, else return false."

Here is my code so far:

```
  if (pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) {
    return true 
  } else {
    return false
    }
 if ((pin.matches(/\b(\w)/g))) {
      return true
    } else {
      return pin
    }
  }
```

It is only passing some of the tests on codewars. I think I have too many if statements?

Comment: Your function accepts any strings that are length 4 or 6.

Comment: Don't return after the length test passes. Continue on to the digit check. Btw, you can combine the 2 checks into one: `/^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/`

Comment: Where should /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/ be placed?

Comment: It can be the entire function: `function test(pin) { return /^(\d{4}|\d{6})$/.test(pin); }`

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Just add an extra condition that checks to see if the string, once converted to a number, is actually a number.

```js
function test(pin) {
  if ((pin.length === 4 || pin.length === 6) && Number.isInteger(+pin)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

console.log(test('123'));
console.log(test('1234'));
console.log(test('123a'));
console.log(test('asbcf'));
console.log(test('125676'));
```

Comment: Thank you! This has worked. May I ask you what the + does inside the round brackets "(+pin) ?

Comment: It's a shorthand method of converting a number in a string to a real integer. So `'1234'` becomes `1234`.